# Fetching PK column with AI immediately after INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

After data verification, the sql query to populate a row in the Customers table goes something like this

```
mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO Customers (CustFirst, CustLast, CustAddress) 
VALUES ('$CustFirst', '$CustLast', '$CustAddress')")
```

Now that works, pretty straight forward, but the Customers table has 4 columns, CustID being the PK and AI. Do I have to make a new query along the lines of

```
mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT CustID from Customers 
WHERE CustFirst='$CustFirst 
AND CustLast='$CustLast' 
AND CustAddress='$CustAddress')
```

just to retrieve the CustID of the only row being inserted into the table? Or is there a shortcut? I would like to do someting along the lines of

```
echo "The Customer " . $CustFirst . " " . $CustLast . " was added<br>";
echo "with " . $CustID . " being the number associated with the account.";
```

Thanks!

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the tip, I'll will look that up for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$CustID = mysqli_insert_id(connection);
```

You can write above code just after executing your insert query. This will return latest primary key id inserted in your database.